# css transition inside jquery

Tags: jquery, css, transition

Mayby anyone knows why the transition doesn't work! Everything works fine but there is only problem with transition effect...

I tried everything and I can't find the working solution

when I hover one div I would like to change background on the page and it is easy to do it sharply and effect od transition doesn't work (transition-duration of changing image in background

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#niego').hover(function() {
          $('#level3').css({
            'background' : 'background url(photo2.jpg)',
            'background-size' : 'auto 100%',
            'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat',
            'background-position' : 'center top',
            'height' : '100%',
            'background-color' : '#302e2f',
            'transition-duration' : '2s',
            'transition-property' : 'all'
          });
        }, function() {
          // on mouseout, reset the background colour
          $('#level3').css('background', '');
        });
      });
    </script>

    <style>
      #level3
      {
        background: background url(photo1.jpg);
        background-size: auto 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center top;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #302e2f;
        margin-left: 0px;
        transition: all 2s 0s;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="level3">
      <div id="niego"></div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for any hints

Lukas

Comment: Don't you need to include all the browser-specific prefixed properties?

Comment: Why can't you indent your code? Was it so tough?

Comment: Why not use `.animate()`?

Comment: Thank you Pointy - I checked it Chrome and it's working ;)

Comment: @ŁukaszBogocz Why can't you use `:hover` CSS?

Comment: The transition-definition needs to be on the element with no special state, not on the hover-state.